# I tried to rearrange some buttons in my android app but their functions wouldn't go with them

Tags: android, button, swap

So I got 5 buttons on the android home page, I wanted to switch them around so I edited main.xml and all that really swapped were the labels on the buttons.

I've got in the main activity code like

```
View showc = findViewById(R.id.showtheclients);
showc.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.showtheclients:
  ...
```

and I've shifted things around in main.xml but they still have their old functions.
Any advice on how to fix this would be really appreciated.

I'm running Eclipse and Android 1.6 if that helps.

Edit: OK I changed all the views to buttons as was suggested, also I changed one of the IDs in the main.xml (and all the calls in the main activity) and it finally seemed to register that I've changed the order of the buttons (I also swapped IDs the first time since someone asked). ALso I re-installed it on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You say all you shifted was the labels. I assume you mean that you only changed the text on the buttons, and left their IDs as the old ones.

Android uses these IDs to identify your Views. If you're changing what a particular button does, you'll need to change the code for that ID's case statement as well.

PS: It would be better to use

```
Button showc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showtheclients);
```

Instead of

```
View showc = findViewById(R.id.showtheclients);
```

Comment: No I went to the xml and cut and pasted the entire button tags

Comment: The button thing was just a better practice, not a solution. You'll need to post some of your XML and java to be helped further.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your `R.java` file manually and then try it will work. I have face the same problem in my app also this tricks worked for me.